# Time to say goodbye to lila

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's time to make this official: our moderator lila will be losing her diamond.

She hasn't visited the site or performed any moderator action in half a year. The last we heard of her was during a difficult time for her and a still raging covid pandemic that didn't improve anyone's mood. We respect her decision to take time off for herself and wish her the very best for her future.

Lila's legacy lives on in the shape of *several thousand* posts with corrected typos, improved grammar, punctuation and formatting and overall readability. For an outsider that might sound trivial, but for a site that intends to be an encyclopedia of all answers, that vastly increases credibility and comprehensibility for anyone who ever visits these improved questions and answers again.

Her active participation in our chat has breathed fresh life into the dusty place and knit our community so much tighter together. Her hand drawn pictures have brought a smile to many faces and her jokes and movie quotes have transformed many smiles into laughs.

Lila, we miss you. If you ever decide to participate again, rest assured that you will always be welcome.

Comment: Lila is the #1 [prolific editor](https://data.stackexchange.com/pets/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors) with 1385 edits on questions and 1202 edits on answers.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all your hard work, Lila!

Answer (score 3):

We miss you, lila, thank you for all your hard work and all you brought to the chat!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the kind and productive discussion of CO2 formulas ^^

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit surprised. I loved seeing Lila in various chatrooms. Lila will be missed!